# Is there a way to force a re-render of a child component from the parent component without using changing its props in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

#### The problem

I have a parent (X) component that manages a lot of states and children components.

Among these children, I have an animated component (Y) (it is an avatar that has different faces and changes faces in sync with what he says).

For now, the type of face is a state in X and is given as a prop to Y. This mechanism is done by setting a list of timers which will change the state at the required times. I need to have the logic of types of faces inside X because I deal with the speech of the avatar inside X.

The problem is that, when speaking, the avatar changes faces very frequently, causing too frequent re-renders of all the children.

#### The things that I had tried so far

1. One solution that I tried was to wrap the other children in `React.memo()` to avoid the excessive re-renders.

   In that case, I have a problem:

   > One of the children (Z) is wrapping a button that causes the avatar to speak, using as `onClick()` function the `sayText()` function given from X as a prop. For Z, using `React.memo()` is not sufficient. Indeed, when I use React Profiler, I see that Z still re-renders each time the parent re-renders because it says that the `sayText()` prop changes. For this, a solution could be to implement a custom props check for the `React.memo()` but since `sayText()` is dependent on other states (the appearance of the avatar, its voice etc...), I can't just memoize it once.
2. The alternative I thought about was: I could avoid having the type of face as a state but just force a re-render of a Y from X by giving it the new type of face. But I don't know if it is possible and it does not seem like a good idea any way. Anyway, does somebody know if it is possible ?

Or can somebody give me advices on how to organize this better to avoid the initial problem ?

I can give more details if you need in comments.

Comment: `causing too frequent re-renders of all the children.` 1. Are you noticing performance issues? 2. Show some code.

Comment: My problem is that due to re-renders, some buttons are not clickable for a long time during the speech, so this can be viewed as performance issue yes. I think the code is too big to be shared here.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to move all the non-speech/avater children (and associated state) outside of X into Z (a new parent component).

Z renders X and all of X's old children, and X renders just the speech/avater related stuff.

Answer (score 2):

```
sayText
```

Wrap the above function in [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback), then if you used `React.memo` on child component `Z`, it should not re-render anymore because the returned callback will be the same if its dependencies don't change.

Comment: how should I set the dependency array in that case ? do I need to manually list all the states that are used in sayText() ?

Comment: @aurelien_morel yeah just follow useCallback docs

Comment: this requires that I completly copy the function in the useCallback and have it doubled in the code which feels weird

Comment: @aurelien_morel You should not duplicate it you should have one instance returned from `useCallback`